# Validity and satisfiability

Tags: logic

I am having problems understanding the difference between validity and satisfiability. 
Given the following:

(i) For all F, F is satisfiable or ~F is satisfiable.

(ii) For all F, F is valid or ~F is valid.

How do I prove which is true and which is false?

Statement (i) is true, as for all F, F will either be satisfiable, or ~F will be satisfiable (truth table). However, how do I go about solving for statement (ii)?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Probably better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you really mean scicomp, Louis? "site for scientists using computers to solve scientific problems". Doesn't seem to fit. Correspondingly, there are no tags for logic. Perhaps mathematics?

Comment: The answer provided is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aprilrocks92,

I don't blame you for being confused, because actually logicians, mathematicians, heck even those philosopher types use the words validity differently sometimes.

Trying not to overcomplicate, I'll give you a thin definition: a conclusion if valid when it is true whenever the premises are true. We also say, given a suitably defined logic, that the conclusion follows as a "logical consequence" of the premises.

On the other hand, satisfisability means that there exists a valuation of the non logical symbols in the formula F that makes the formula true in the logic.

So I should probably mention the difference between semantics and syntax to explain. The syntax of your logic is all those logical and non logical symbols, and the deductive rules that enable you to make "steps" towards proof in the logic. My definition of satisfisability above mentioned the word "valuation"- now how does that fit? Well the answer is that you need to supply a semantics: in short this is the structure that the formula of the logic are expressions of, usually given in set theory, and a valuation of a given F is a function that maps all the non logical symbols in F to sets and members of sets, which a given semantics for the logic composes into a truth value.

Hmm. I'm not sure that's the best explanation, but I don't have much time.

Either way, that should help you understand the difference. To answer your question about the difference between (i) and (ii) without giving too much away, think: what's the relationship between the two? Well given that as above an F' is *true* given a valuation that sends the sentence to true. So you could "rewrite" my definition of validity as: a conclusion is valid iff whenever the premises are satisfisable the conclusion is satisfisable.

Now, with regards your requirement to prove these things, I strongly suspect you've got a lot more context about your logic you're not telling us and your teacher or text book has intimated a context in which to answer these, as actually taken in the general sense your question doesn't make complete sense.